# Can I resize an image uploaded in an Xpages Upload File Control?

Tags: xpages

I have a user facing app where users are supposed to upload pictures. I am concerned they will not follow instructions (that is rare indeed) and load up huge files. Is there a way I can resize an image that the user uploads?

Comment: a bit off topic: please, tell users their pictures were manipulated and allow them to see the result or control the amount of resize/compression.

Answer (score 3):

David Leedy is doing some of this, specifically with JPEG images, in his File Vault app he demoed at MWLUG 2014. You could probably poke around [the Processor Class](//bitbucket.org/leedy/filevault/src/023754e49558acc59def968a06944fe3353e885d/nsf.fileVault.bikedemo/Code/Java/com/notesin9/filevault/Processor.java?at=default) he has and see how he's doing it there, [his repo is on Bitbucket](//bitbucket.org/leedy/filevault).

The [Ni9 announcing this is #150](//www.notesin9.com/2014/08/01/notesin9-150-announcing-filevault-for-xpages/). I would recommend watching it and poking around his code. Obviously your task is handling jpegs, gifs, pngs or whatever formats you allow. Each would need to be handled separately, with an image manipulation class that can handle each format. David is using [*java.awt.Graphics2D*](//docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html), but you may wish to check into [imgscalr](//github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr), which attempts to handle each of the three formats, though it seems to [get fun with gifs](//github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr/issues/73).

[Edit]
As David Leedy mentioned in the comments, it's worth looking at the [javaxt.io.Image Class](//www.javaxt.com/javaxt-core/javaxt.io.Image/) from JavaXT (which intends to extend the core of Java.
[/Edit]

Comment: There's another great library out there - Java-XT that has a lot of image manipulation  tools.  Should make it much easier to convert pictures from XPages.  We're in the process of re-writing this at the day job (Devin's working it) and I hope to update the fileVault project once that's done.

Comment: I'm excited to see your next version of fileVault.

Answer (score 1):

Eric's answer is good, but only covers **server-side resizing**. It is also possible to resize images **client-side** (before sending them to the server).

What you need depends on the requirements: e.g. if you have users on a cellular network, don't need full 5 megapixel images and want to improve the upload speed you need client-side resizing (with possibly some added server side validations). For client-side resizing I can recommend looking into the [JavaScript Load Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) library by Blueimp. He also created a [multiple file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) widget that can do a lot of things, like creating multiple resized versions of an image in the client and sending all those to the server.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I knew that there were client-side implementations, but I hadn't realized it could be as easy as that JS Load Image approach. This is a good fit for a feature addition to an UnPlugged app I have in production. :-D

Comment: If it's for Unplugged, then take a look at the photo upload control in the XControls: it uses the library I mentioned above.